# Resampling the Google Earth Engine Sentinel 5 Images in High Resolution

Tags: python, arcgis, google-earth-engine

I downloaded a Sentinel-5 image (visible bands + NIR) in high resolution. However, once in ArcGIS pro, I noticed that the resolution was high and cell size is big. Is there any way to resampling the cell size 30*30?

Thank you.

[https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e8757a16852f39c7853ca594273a3a5](https://stackoverflow.com)

I want to reduce the cell size 30*30 pixel. What's the way can i follow or any specific code that's i am following to reduce the cell size.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)